# SQLite Query _ Select only different Varchar and add them to one

Tags: sql, sqlite

this might sound kind of strange, but what I want to do is this:

[SQLite table  @ SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/10cbe/1)

**I want as result:**

> peter

**when I query ID<=5**

*and*

> alvinpeter

**if ID is <=10** (*names added to one in alphabetical order*)

Anyone know how to do this with SQLite only?

Thanks in advance, best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following will do:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name,'')
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT name
  FROM testtable
  WHERE ID<=10
  ORDER BY name
);
```

(in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/10cbe/13))